# how to join three or more tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables and I want retrieve values from them for which I use following query which gives me error, can anybody tell me what's wrong?

```
SELECT a.VISITOR_TEXT,a.COMPANY_TEXT,a.CONTACT,a.PERSON_TO_MEET,a.DEPARTMENT_TEXT,a.FLOOR,b.BELONGING_T
YPE,b.BELONGING_TEXT ,a.INTIME, c.EXIT_TIME FROM tm_visitor a  LEFT JOIN tm_belonging b , tm_exit c ON a.ID=b.
BID AND a.ID=c.ID;
```

Comment: @ jcho360: When did i not said thanks to ppl who help
I said thanks also and also accepted the answers which were provided to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  a.VISITOR_TEXT,
        a.COMPANY_TEXT,
        a.CONTACT,
        a.PERSON_TO_MEET,
        a.DEPARTMENT_TEXT,
        a.FLOOR,
        b.BELONGING_TYPE,
        b.BELONGING_TEXT,
        a.INTIME,
        c.EXIT_TIME 
FROM    tm_visitor a  
        LEFT JOIN tm_belonging b ON b.BID = a.id
        LEFT JOIN tm_exit c ON c.ID = a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.VISITOR_TEXT,a.COMPANY_TEXT,a.CONTACT,a.PERSON_TO_MEET,a.DEPARTMENT_TEXT,a.FLOOR,b.BELONGING_TYPE,b.BELONGING_TEXT ,a.INTIME, c.EXIT_TIME FROM tm_visitor a  
LEFT JOIN tm_belonging b ON a.ID=b.BID 
LEFT JOIN tm_exit c ON a.ID=c.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `,` with the join syntax. Only in the from syntax. Use

```
SELECT  a.VISITOR_TEXT, a.COMPANY_TEXT,a.CONTACT, a.PERSON_TO_MEET,a.DEPARTMENT_TEXT, a.FLOOR,b.BELONGING_TYPE,b.BELONGING_TEXT, a.INTIME, c.EXIT_TIME 
FROM tm_visitor a  
LEFT JOIN tm_belonging b  ON a.ID=b.BID
left join tm_exit c ON a.ID=c.ID
```